# Is there any way to close MqttClient Threads spawned in the backend?

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

We have a streaming application taking data from [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT) and load into other resource. And this application have multiple threads to handle some tasks.

Here we have two tasks(threads):

- First one is a *READER*
- Second one is a *WRITER*

So *READER* will read data from MQTT broker and write on a java queue and *WRITER* will take this data from that queue and write it over one database. This application itself monitoring these threads for finding any failure. If any one of the threads failed then we will stop remaining threads gracefully. In case of paho MqttClient class (*READER* Class) wont create a thread even its a threaded class. But it will creating multiple threads in the background.

Because of this we could not check whether these threads is failed or running by java `isAlive()` function. So we just checking this class have connection by MqttClient `isConnected()` method. Once `isConnected` method return false (5 times) , then we will stop Writer thread gracefully. But Reader class threads which spawned in the background are not able to stop. I have tried `disconnect()` and `close()`
methods. But its not stopping any of the background threads. Its throws error disconnected threads could not stop.

So please anybody help.

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest sounds like an awkward design.

Why not just use the Paho callbacks, in particular the [connectionLost](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttCallback.html) as below?

```
private final MqttCallbackExtended mCallback = new MqttCallbackExtended() {
    @Override
    public void connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String brokerAddress) {
            mqttClient.subscribe("topic", 1, null, mSubscribeCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable ex) {
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken deliveryToken) {
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
    }
};

private final IMqttActionListener mConnectionCallback = new IMqttActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
        // do nothing, this case is handled in mCallback.connectComplete()
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
    }
};

private final IMqttActionListener mSubscribeCallback = new IMqttActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken subscribeToken) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(IMqttToken subscribeToken, Throwable ex) {
    }

};

MqttConnectOptions connectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
connectOptions.setCleanSession(true);
connectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);     
connectOptions.setUserName("username");
connectOptions.setPassword("password".toCharArray());

MqttAsyncClient mqttClient = new MqttAsyncClient("tcp:// test.mosquitto.org");
mqttClient.setCallback(mCallback);

try {
    mqttClient.connect(connectOptions, null, mConnectionCallback);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.toString());
}
```